# Как изменить textbox формы из другого класса?

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток. Мне необходимо изменять значение textbox из другого класса, смог разобраться как это делать с помощью данного видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9qcKV4j75U. Единственная проблема в том, что я смог изменять значение textbox при нажатии кнопки. Вот небольшой пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Worker _worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sendMessageButton.Click += Button1_Click;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _worker = new Worker();

        _worker.SendMessage += _worker_SendMessage1;

        Thread thread = new Thread(_worker.Work);
        thread.Start();

        if (_worker != null)
            _worker.SendMessageToTB();
    }

    private void _worker_SendMessage1(string mess)
    {
        ChatTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ChatTextBox.Text += mess));
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    private string mess = "Кажется, ты что-то нажал...\r\n";
    private bool _sendMessage = false;

    public void SendMessageToTB()
    {
        _sendMessage = true;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        if (_sendMessage)
        {
            SendMessage(mess);
            _sendMessage = false;
        }
    }

    public event Action<string> SendMessage;
}
}
```

Для моей же программы нужно сделать так, чтобы значение текст бокса изменялось без всяких нажатий на кнопку. Суть в том, что как только серверу от пользователя приходит сообщение он (сервер) должен это сообщение не только отправить всем остальным подключенным пользователям (за это отвечает метод server.BroadcastMessage), но и вывести в textbox своей формы. К сожалению сам так и не могу с этим разобраться, никак не выводится у меня текст в textbox.
Вот код программы.
Класс работы сервера:

```
public class ClientObject
 {
    public event Action<string> SendMessage;

    internal string Id { get; private set; }
    internal NetworkStream Stream { get; set; }
    string userName;
    TcpClient client;
    ServerObject server;

    public ClientObject() { }
    public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient, ServerObject serverObject)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client = tcpClient;
        server = serverObject;
        server.AddConnection(this);
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        try
        {
            // Возвращаем объект NetWorkStream, используемый для отправки и получения данных
            Stream = client.GetStream();

            // Получаем имя пользователя
            userName = GetMessage();
            string message = userName + " вошел в чат.";
            // Рассылаем сообщение о входе в чат всем подключенным пользователям
            server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id); // отправляем сообщение всем подключенным пользователям
            SendMessage(message); // Данный текст должен быть записан в textbox формы

            // Получаем данные от пользователя
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    message = GetMessage();
                    message = string.Format($"{userName}: {message}");
                    server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
                    SendMessage(message); // Данный текст должен быть записан в textbox формы
                }
                catch
                {
                    message = userName + " покинул чат.";
                    server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
                    SendMessage(message); // Данный текст должен быть записан в textbox формы
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Удаляем пользователя из списка подключенных пользователей и закрываем поток с соединением
            server.RemoveConnection(Id);
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Формы:

```
namespace Server
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static ServerObject server;
    static Thread listenerThread;

    private ClientObject cl = new ClientObject();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cl.SendMessage += Cl_SendMessage; // Подписываемся на событие

        try
        {
            server = new ServerObject();
            listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Listen));
            listenerThread.Start(); // старт потока
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            server.Disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void Cl_SendMessage(string mess)
    {
        chatLogTB.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => chatLogTB.Text += mess));
    }
}
}
```

Очень надеюсь, что кто-нибудь поможет или подскажет как правильно реализовать то, что мне нужно.
P.S. вот ссылка на весь проект целиком, может вы найдете в чем ошибка: http://rgho.st/8gTqYzFrP

Comment: chat.LogTB.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>{chatLogTD.Text+=mess     }));

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно воспользоваться событиями.

Подписываешь 1 форму на события другой формы и обрабатываешь реакцию на это событие.

Говорят, что это самый правильный путь.

2. Можно создать открытый метод у формы и с помощью него взаимодействовать с другой формой.